# SSH connect to a docker container directly, without ssh the host first

Tags: ssh, terminal, docker, sftp, container

On my local computer, I connect with ssh to a distant VPS: `ssh user@1.2.3.4`.

In this VPS, a docker container is running (for example `docker pull nvidia/cuda:11.4.0-devel-ubuntu18.04` and `docker run -itd --name test nvidia/cuda:11.4.0-devel-ubuntu18.04 ...`)

```
Local computer -> VPS (1.2.3.4) -> Docker container
```

**What is the standard way to connect directly from my local computer to this container via SSH and directly have a bash prompt?**

Is it possible to do it in one step *instead of*:

```
ssh user@1.2.3.4
docker attach test
```

In the same way, I would like to connect the Docker container with SFTP (for example with Filezilla) from my local computer.

Comment: It's not clear if you want to connect directly to an SSH server running in the container, or if you just want to combine your current process into one command. For the former, I would recommend against this as a container should generally have one service per container. For the latter, have you tried `ssh user@1.2.3.4 docker attach test`?

Comment: @cherdt I would also like to browse the container's files with a SFTP client on my local computer, I don't think this is possible with docker attach? What is the easiest solution to do this?

Comment: I suspect the down-vote was because the thing you have asked for is actively discouraged by docker.

Answer (score 5):

Docker is not as a virtual machine<sup>1</sup> and there is no standard way to connect directly a container from a remote machine.  In fact this type of behaviour is actively discouraged with docker.

To do what you're asking would require you to run an SSH server inside your container as well as whatever app it's supposed to contain.  Docker recommends that you don't do this:

> [**Run multiple services in a container**](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/)
>
> A container’s main running process is the `ENTRYPOINT` and/or `CMD` at the end of the Dockerfile.  It is generally recommended that you separate areas of concern by using **one service per container**.

You should also try to think of containers as disposable.  That is to say `docker container rm ...` should never destroy anything that can't be recovered with a `docker run ...`.  If you are trying to manually edit or upload to the container *(not a volume)* then the chances are that you would then care if the container was destroyed.

### Thinking about the problem differently...

I believe that what you want to achieve is to have easy upload/download of files to your `nvidia/cuda` container.  There's two ways to achieve this...

### 1 - Use a bind mount, and ssh / scp directly to your host

A [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) would result in a directory being shared between your host and your container.  You could, very simply, ssh into your host and browse these files on the host.  All the files on your host will be the same as those in the container (not a copy).  So any changes you make will be instantly seen the container.

### 2 - Use two containers with a shared volume or bind mount

If you want to isolate the SSH instance from that of your host machine, you could have a second container running an SSH server (eg: [this image](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/openssh-server)) with the same bind-mount or docker volume as your `nvidia/cuda` container.

Any files changed in the volume by an SSH client will be seen by your main "nvidia/cuda" container because, once again, they are the same files and not a copy.

A common pattern when doing this is to have one volume mounted to `/data` in both containers.  That way you know `/data` in one container is the same as `/data` in the other.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Isn't there a simpler way, if we accept the fact that a container runs 2 services (example: computation  + SSH)?

Comment: @Basj of course it's possible if you build your own images, and that's basically what's discussed [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/).  But it's not "the standard way".  And from experience, it's not more complex... it's just that multiple containers is unintuitive *at first*.  When you get used to it it's it makes things much easier because you never care about what is going on inside your containers.  By keeping anything you want saved in volumes, you can just tear down and re-deploy later images whenever you like.

Comment: I should add that it's now very common to only deploy docker containers through some sort of service manager such as Kubernetes, Docker-compose, AWS ECS.  These make the whole process much more slick and allow you to define all your containers and volumes etc in on configuration.

Comment: Thanks @PhilipCouling. Could you add in your answer a solution with a "single container" containing both computation and ssh? Maybe an example Dockerfile based on `nvidia/cuda` would be enlightening for me and future readers :) Thanks!